# Azure - Backup Web App to network protected storage

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

We currently have set up a web application in our Azure enviroment which is connected to our VNET and reachable through private link.

Now we are trying to set up backups to an Azure storage account.

this storage account is also connected to the VNET and only allows connections from this. We have set an Exception on "Allow trusted microsoft services to access this storage account"

However, when we try to run the backup of the web app, we get the following error:

"Storage access failed. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.. Please delete and recreate backup schedule to mitigate."

We have had this same issue when restoring SQL databases through azure storage and temporary made it accessible for all which made it work, however this is not feasible for the future, is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue.
Unfortunately a backup in combination with a firewall is not possible according to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-backup#requirements-and-restrictions).

"Using a firewall enabled storage account as the destination for your backups is not supported. If a backup is configured, you will get failed backups."

Kind regards

Comment: Well that kinda sucks.... this would mean we could not 100% secure our backups which are only required for us and not for any external party.

Comment: At https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/34523428-enable-storage-account-firewall-to-access-from-app?page=1&per_page=20 are some workarounds discussed. Maybe this one helps:
"Your Azure storage IP address can be added to IP ADDRESSES ROUTED TO VNet under Virtual Network Integration for the application service."